# Can our imam act as wali for our nikkah, when my intended wife's family only allow her to date?

Tags: nikah, wali

I am a 21 year-old Muslim, reverted 3 years ago to Islam, and now I would like to get married.  I met a 16 year-old girl and she is interested in getting married, but her family are non-practicing Muslims and they only allow her to date. I want to know if we can get our imam has wali to make the nikkah?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: You must be aware that if you are living in a non-Muslim society maybe it would be illegal to marry a girl of that age. An Imam can only be a wali if the wali rejects and the future spouse asked a (shari'a) court to marry her as her father the primary wali has rejected to marry her (to a good Muslim) for no good reason according shari'a. So It is better to either convince her father or wait or at least ask for her hand and get to know her as a fiancé during your time of engagement.